# Web-service accessibility by swing tool

Tags: java, web-services

i am trying to make a tool through swing programme ,the tool consist of two phases only

1)**user authentication via LDAP & oracle:** username,password,group name

2)  Web-service: if user is authorised to use webservice,than only he can use it.

**Problem**:user authentication is allright,but how to use webservices with it.please share your ideas.with respect to web services my knowledge is zero....
i do have a WSDL file.but how to use that with an associated user.

Answer (score 0):

Put aside swing for a moment and get the web service call working on its own. There is plenty of information around about how to call web services ([search stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[java]+calling+web+service)).

Once you've mastered that, then integrate your ws client with your swing app.